How to switch back to grid layout in Pgadmin 4.8.11
Initially I had my table in the grid view, but accidently I have made it into the below layout. I am unable to figure out how to switch it back to grid layout. I am working in Pgadmin 4.8.11. Appreciate, if someone can help me to change this layout. I couldn't find any steps related to switching it back, although I went through the settings available.

You must be using a very old browser version. Upgrade you browser version.
Please check - https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/7963.
